# Devise and security: 3 admin-roles with booleans. Is this 100% secure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, devise

I have defined 3 admin-roles for my Devise-based application. God_mode, normal_mode and guest_mode. They are all booleans. But I was wondering if there is NO WAY to get around somehow faking a request and sending through an 'admin god_mode: True'-request for a normal-admin or guest admin? Through mass-assignment or similar ways to attack my application.

I simply want to know if this is completely unhackable and 100% secure.

For the example's own sake, Ive scaffolded up the CRUD-part of the application (Not gonna do that in the real World), but params part is the same. Devise configurations are default / out of the box.

I basically have 3 admin-roles(booleans), and a "before_action :authenticate_admin!" + a private method with client_params with params.require(:client).permit(:name, :description) - I am wondering if this in itself is enough to keep my website safe from malicious attacks. We assume that I know how to protect my own computer, not getting phished, etc.

I've googled a lot, and unfortunately a lot of rails 3 articles still pops-up and are based around the outdated(?) attr_accessible and similar. I know we use strong-params now, but it all just seems too-good-to-be-true for me - Isn't there any way to hack'n'crack your way into changing your guest-admin role into admin god_mode in this example?

Clients.rb

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_client, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

before_action :authenticate_admin!


# GET /clients
# GET /clients.json
def index
  @clients = Client.all
end

# GET /clients/1
# GET /clients/1.json

def show
end

# GET /clients/new

def new
  @client = Client.new
end

# GET /clients/1/edit

def edit
end

# POST /clients
# POST /clients.json

def create
@client = Client.new(client_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @client.save
    format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @client }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
  end

# PATCH/PUT /clients/1
# PATCH/PUT /clients/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @client.update(client_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @client }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /clients/1
# DELETE /clients/1.json
def destroy
  @client.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to clients_url, notice: 'Client was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_client
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(:name, :description)
  end
  end
```

**The schmema:** (Admins should have a default-value=false though:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160825190018) do

  create_table "admins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.boolean  "god_mode"
    t.boolean  "normal_mode"
    t.boolean  "guest_mode"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admins_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admins_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: nothing is ever 100% crack proof......but as far as it can be, rails and devise do a pretty good job out of the box. so long as you don't put password information in a get request or store passwords in your db you should be fine.  always encrypt yeah? But devise does that automatically for you anyways so you should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change a couple of things in your code:

- Instead of having 3 boolean fields in your database to store the role of the user, I would store an integer representing that role. This way, you will be able to add more roles whenever you need them. In addition, nothing prevents you from setting more than one of these flags to true, leaving a strange configuration.
- Instead of checking whether a user is an admin or not (which seems to be what `before_action :authenticate_admin!` is there for), I would check if the logged user has permissions to do a certain task. In each action I would check whether the logged user has permissions to create users, update users, etc. These permissions would be defined in a file where you only say which roles can do what. It may be useful to have a look at [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) (Rails 3) or [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) (Rails > 3). The reason to do this is that at some point you might want to allow another roles to do something with your users (maybe index?), and you will just have to modify your permissions file to allow them accessing your users list. Without even touching the controller.

Finally, just wanted to state that in terms of security nobody can guarantee that a system is unhackable. Even if you do your best to keep your services safe, 0 day vulnerabilities, 3rd-party gems or human mistakes (code errors, missconfigured servers / routers, ...) could leave a small hole that could be big enough for an attacker to get in.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Really appreciate the help! I think it makes good sense with point 1. Question: Do you have an example of point 1 & 2 - How that code would look? That would make it easier for me to grasp and google further on for tutorials and documentation

Comment: For point 2 I recommend reading the documentation, is full of examples. 

For point 1 I would define a Role class with a hash associating role_ids with role names. After that, I would define a single field in your User model which would store a value from the keys of that hash